# Python loop to split a dataframe by a particular row/index for writing the sub-dataframes into csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe having around 18 million rows, I want to create a loop to split the entire dataframe by 100000 rows each sub-dataframe and write them to csv file, so that it can be displayed in excel without any loss of data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQOIZ.png)

I was able to split the data using this, but i want to be able to write to csv file in the loop itself
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgCXN.png)

Comment: You need to share your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over chunck of size 100000. In each iteration each df has 100000 rows. They are saved as the i-th iteration name to a csv file.

```
for i, df in enumerate(pd.read_csv("dataframe.csv", chunksize=100000)):
    df.to_csv(f'{i}.csv')
```

Comment: requires explanation as to what is happening. ..

Comment: @D.L I added explaination